# Как часть String передать в другой String

Tags: java, android, строки

есть у меня строка String time. В нее каждую минуту записываются новые данные, сама строка выглядит как то так: 
 `Время по МСК 18:20 Время в США: 04:53 Время в ОАЭ: 01:27`
Меня интересует то, как из переменной Time достать значения и записать в другую переменную, таким образом московское время должна быьь в переменной mskTime в сша время должно так usaTime ну и время в ОАЭ в переменной arabianTime. И да, именно из переменной time достать и после записывать ее значения в другие. (можно конечно и по другому, но реализация примерно должна быть такая.)

Comment: Такая себя реализация. Откуда вы берёте значения дат? Почему не записывать каждую дату в свою переменную типа String? Может код предоставите? Кто знает, что там ещё за чудесные реализации представлены

Comment: Там парсинг через jsoup, а я не знаю как там в разные переменные записать числа.

Comment: Если парсите html-документ, посмотрите, в каких тегах/атрибутах находятся эти данные, и парсите по атрибутам.

Comment: Там все вместе записаны, в один div в котором h1

Comment: Значит, парсите строку. Например, split("Время") и далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
String time = "Время по МСК 18:20 Время в США: 04:53 Время в ОАЭ: 01:27";
String[] times = time.split("\\s*[А-Яа-я\\s:]*\\s+");

String mskTime = times[1];
String usaTime = times[2];
String oaeTime = times[3];

System.out.println(mskTime);
System.out.println(usaTime);
System.out.println(oaeTime);

//18:20
//04:53
//01:27
```

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте через String.substring(int start, int end), какая реализация - такое и решение